# Echo PHP into file linux

Tags: php, linux, bash, tee

I'm trying to programatically create a PHP file:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['code'])
{
  // Do 1
}
else
{
  // Do else
}
?>
```

I've got this:

```
sudo echo '<?php
if (!empty($_GET['code']))
{
}
else
{
}
?>' | sudo tee -a /var/www/html/index.php
```

But that's stripping out the single quotes from around the `code` ... I've tried all sorts such as double quotes and escaping the single quotes.

I'm sure this is simple! Help! :)

Comment: Did you try double quotes around `code` and single quotes around it all?

Comment: That did it. :) Thanks!

Comment: @Adder that's definitely a way around. Thought this approach is generally troublesome when applied to other (more complicated) scenarios. Please see my answer on how it's recommended to do by `shellcheck` (which is a very nice shell linter).

Comment: `sudo echo` is just silly. There is absolutely no need to obtain root privileges to write to standard output.

Answer (score 1):

This is how single quotes should be escaped in `bash` and pretty much any shell:

```
echo '<?php
if (!empty($_GET['\'code\'']))
{
} else {
}
?>' | tee /var/www/html/index.php
```

See also: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1003